# Is this usage of "convinced" correct?

Tags: word-usage

To me, this is the normal usage of the word:

> Mary convinced Tom to wear a dress.

How about this one:

> Tom nodded, convinced to wear a dress.

I think I've never seen this usage before, so I'm not sure if it's correct.

Note: I searched on [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22convinced%20to%20pick%20a%22&ei=o57BW76kBsKY8QXYlabgDQ&start=10&sa=N&biw=1855&bih=941), but I couldn't find this sentence structure.

Comment: Your Google search was far too narrow.  There was no need to search for `convinced to pick a` when what you wanted to find is "convinced to".

Comment: Again, search Google Books, not websites. You will get far more *reliable* results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly correct to use **convinced** in a past participial clause  like that.

You may use it, convinced that it's correct.

It can take an infinitive clause complement or a (sometimes reduced) that-clause complement.

> He voted for the guy, convinced (that) it was the right thing to do.
>
> He took the back roads instead of the highway, convinced by a few locals to take that route.

Comment: I'm curious, what's the difference between the version with "that" and the version without "that"?

Comment: When convinced of a truth or fact ("it was the right thing"), the thing is usually expressed with a *that*-clause.  When convinced to carry out a course of action ("to take that route"), the action is usually expressed with an infinitival clause.